how can I remove all default settings in Gutenberg blocks? example core/button
I’m expanding the capabilities of the default Gutenberg block (core/button) and want to hide all the default settings.
This code helps to hide all settings except 1
//functions.php
    function disable_all_block_settings($metadata)
    {
        if ($metadata['name'] === 'core/button') {
            $metadata['supports'] = [];
            $metadata['styles'] = [];
        }

        if ($metadata['name'] === 'core/buttons') {
            $metadata['supports'] = [];
        }
        return $metadata;
    }

    add_filter('block_type_metadata', 'disable_all_block_settings');



this seems to be a core issue that still needs to be fixed:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/19796
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/42079

Most likely yes, what was suggested in the article did not work for me
